# Vector notation of all entries 1

Tags: notation, vectors

Is there any notation describing a vector with all components being 1? Or whether the bold-face one $\mathrm 1$ is publicly acknowledged as it?

Comment: Every time I have seen that notation used and unexplained, I've been confused by it. It took me longer than I care to admit to figure out that someone was using $11^T$ to represent a square matrix populated entirely with $1$'s.

So, if you use it in your writing, I suggest explaining it the first time you do so.

Comment: I don't think there's a special symbol reserved for it, but $v = (1, \dots, 1)$ seems straightforward enough.

Comment: On MathOverflow: [Notation for the all-ones vector](http://mathoverflow.net/q/9898).

Comment: what about $[\delta_{11}]_{m\times n}$ ?

Comment: On MathOverflow: [Notation for the all-ones vector](https://mathoverflow.net/q/9898).

Answer (score 9):

I know that in computer science the zero-vector is writen $\vec{0}$, and sometime they extend it to the"ones"-vector $\vec{1}$.

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

I have seen $\mathbf {j} $ used for the all 1's vector with $\mathbf {J} $ used for the all 1's matrix.

Comment: Is there any reference?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones) uses this notation

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen the usage of a "\mathbb{1}" for it, I think it is more clear than others, however mathbb doesn't support digits, there are some options using other packages which you may find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715099/vector-notation-of-all-entries-1).